# VBA - How to get sheet codename index

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following to get the sheet codename, but I would like to get just the index of that codename. Lets say the codename is "Sheet4" I would like to get just the number 4. If it's "Sheet12" I would like just the 12.

```
ActiveSheet.CodeName
```

Thanks!

Comment: for the General Problem look into regexm you are searching something like this: reg.Pattern = "[^\d]+"
Debug.Print reg.Replace(yourstring, "")
But for this specific question the answer from Mrig will probably do

Comment: Hi @DoktorOSwaldo I do not know how to apply your suggestion. Could you please help? The answer from Mrig responds to another issue, not what I am looking for.

Comment: Just to be clear "the index of that codename" makes no sense - a sheet's codename can be whatever you want it to be. Your question is merely asking how to extract numbers from the end of a string. I can change a sheet's codename to Sheet99 but it doesn't make it the 99th sheet in the workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay to extract the Numbers of a String they are basically two ways.
First you could write a Function which will extract all nummeric chars from your string:

```
Function ExtractNumericChars(sInput As String) As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim sResult As String
Dim sChr As String

For i = 1 To Len(sInput)
    sChr = Mid(sInput, i, 1)
    If IsNumeric(sChr) Then
        sResult = sResult & sChr
    End If
Next

removeBadChars = sResult

End Function
```

This works fine for your case. The more elegant way would be using a Regex.
This would Need the reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5". The Advantage is, that you basically can match anything with regex. In your case it would look like the following:

```
Dim regEx As New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "[^\d]+"
Debug.Print regEx.Replace(ActiveSheet.CodeName, "")
```

Answer (score 3):

It's simple:

```
  ActiveSheet.Index
```

Comment: That does not give the index of the codename, but the index of the sheet.

Comment: Do you want the number part of the codename? If yes, do all the codename of worksheets start with "Sheet" like: Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3,..., Sheet11, Sheet12, ... and so on?

Comment: That's what's happening now. The thing is that I would like to run a For Loop in some sheets based on their codename index (the number part of the codename as you said).

Comment: You can do that using- `Right(ActiveSheet.CodeName, Len(ActiveSheet.CodeName) - 5)`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a function which gives me the sheet based on its codename.

```
Function GetSheetWithCodename(ByVal worksheetCodename As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Worksheet
    Dim iSheet As Long
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' mimics the default behaviour
    For iSheet = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        If wb.Worksheets(iSheet).CodeName = worksheetCodename Then
            Set GetSheetWithCodename = wb.Worksheets(iSheet)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next iSheet
End Function
```